# read mixed data into R

Tags: json, r

I have a text file '\t' separated. First two columns are text and third one is in JSON format like `{type: [{a: a1, timestamp: 1}, {a:a2, timestamp: 2}]}`
How can i put it into DF correctly?

I would like to parse line like `factor1\tparam1\t{type: [{a: a1, timestamp: 1}, {a:a2, timestamp: 2}]}` into DF like

```
factor_column  param_column   a_column  ts_column
    factor1        param1        a1         1    
    factor1        param1        a2         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have saved that one line of text you have provided into a file called 'parseJSON.txt'. You can then read the file in as per usual using `read.table`, then make use of `library(jsonlite)` to parse the 3rd column.

I've also formatted the line of text to include quotes around the JSON code: 
`factor1    param1  {"type": [{"a": "a1", "timestamp": 1}, {"a":"a2", "timestamp": 2}]}`

```
library(jsonlite)

dat <- read.table("parseJSON.txt", 
              sep="\t", 
              header=F,
              quote="")

#parse 3rd column using jsonlite
js <- fromJSON(as.character(dat[1,3]))
```

`js` is now a `list`

```
> js
$type
   a timestamp
1 a1         1
2 a2         2
```

which can be combined with the first two columns of `dat`

```
res <- cbind(dat[,1:2],js$type)

names(res) <- c("factor_column", "param_column", "a_column", "ts_column")
```

which gives

```
> res
     factor_column param_column a_column ts_column
1       factor1       param1       a1         1
2       factor1       param1       a2         2
```

Comment: Thanks, tospig! Trouble is that my input file is huge and I can't just add quotes manualy as you did. Any suggestion how to parse 'almost-json' line?

Comment: I would first check how the data is generated and see if you can produce 'actual' JSON with the quotes around the `key` strings. If not there may be a way using regular expressions to put quotes around alphanumeric strings, but that's a whole other question

Comment: @crusoe [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29550840/4002530) may be of use for extracting the text to put quotes around?