# r - extract alphanumeric strings from text

Tags: r

**Background**

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29500139/4002530) but not required reading

**Question**

I have a string

```
str_temp <- "{type: [{a: a1, timestamp: 1}, {a:a2, timestamp: 2}]}"
```

from which I would like to extract all the seven alphanumeric substrings: `type, a, a1, timestamp, a, a2, timestamp`. However, I can't get my regex to work.

I have tried both base R and `library(stringr)` using various combinations of `[:word:], [:alnum:], [:alpha:]` etc.

One example:

```
> pattern <- "[:word:]"
> str_locate_all(str_temp, pattern)
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     6   6
[2,]    11  11
[3,]    26  26
[4,]    34  34
[5,]    48  48
```

but this just gives me the **end points** of the strings `type`, `a`, `timestamp`, `a`, `timestamp` and not the start points, or either of `a1` or `a2`.

What's the correct regex for extracting all seven alphanumeric strings?

Comment: Why not go with `strsplit()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a regex that works. matches all alphanumeric words but not numbers.

```
((?![0-9]+)[A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/EuF9AfdtXW

Thanks to Richard for showing how to use this in r:

```
regmatches(str_temp, gregexpr("((?![0-9]+)[A-Za-z0-9]+)", str_temp, perl = TRUE))[[1L]]
```

Comment: I don't think this is valid in `r`

Comment: @tospig - the question is also tagged "regex".  It's a valid regex

Comment: Borrowing this regex, in base R you could use `regmatches(str_temp, gregexpr("((?![0-9]+)[A-Za-z0-9]+)", str_temp, perl = TRUE))[[1L]]`

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven, that works in R. Also, I thought the `r` tag (and title) would indicate I'd like an r solution. I've removed the `regex` tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate on how the regex is capturing these. thanks

Comment: It's using a lookbehind as documented here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html. But basically It matches [A-Za-z0-9]+ which is a non-empty alpha numeric string like ab, a1, 1a, 11 and then ignores any of those strings that match [0-9]+ which leaves ab, a1 and 1a.

Answer (score -1):

```
str_extract_all(str_temp , "([A-Za-z]+)")
[[1]]
[1] "type"      "a"         "a"         "timestamp" "a"         "a"         "timestamp"
```

Comment: This misses `a1` and `a2`